# Some words to describe the situation in a given workplace

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I am an assistant staff in ABC shop. There are 15 staff (including myself) in ABC shop. Some unpleasant things have been happening between the two groups of staff for a long time here. I want to learn how to describe the people in the following situation.

1. The 14 staff can be divided into two groups, group A and group B. Group A dislikes group B and group B does likewise.
2. My job title is the least in the shop. I am both friends of group A and group B, so I am always stuck with the two groups where they argue over something.

For (1), I am writing group A and group B are enemies, but this is too strong and will ruin my diary. I need some gentle words to describe (1).
For (2), is it correct if I say I am working in between the two groups?

Comment: There has been some *dispute* between group A and B. You are in a *[dilemma](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dilemma)* when they fight or argue over something.

Comment: Another way to phrase it might be that you are *stuck in the middle*, which conveys that you are in a difficult place between two alternatives.  "Working in between" is very neutral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say there is ***friction*** between the two teams. I like some of the definitions found at [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/friction) for *friction*:

> - conflict, as between persons having dissimilar ideas or interests
> - clashing between two persons or parties in opinions or work; a disagreement tending to prevent or retard progress
> - figuratively, lack of harmony; mutual irritation; difficulty

Wordnik lists a few appropriate synonyms, too, like:

> ***tension*** - barely controlled hostility or a strained relationship between people or groups
>
> ***discord*** - want [lack] of agreement; absence of unity or harmony in sentiment or action; variance leading to contention and strife; disagreement

So, you could say that there was ***a lot of*** ***friction*** (or *tension*) ***between the two groups***, or ***a lot of discord in the office***.

As for saying that you are "in between" the two groups, you can convey that a  little more accurately by saying that you are ***caught*** *between* the two groups. The word *caught* conveys the notion that you were in an unenviable position. So, you might say something like this:

> ***There was a lot of friction in the workplace, and I was often caught in the middle of it.***

Answer (score 3):

You may write that A and B are **not on good terms** (not 'enemies', 'tis quite a 'strong' word). You are the 'neutral party' - you do not side with 'A' nor side with 'B'.

Comment: The more common phrasing is that they are not **on** good terms.